# how can i get value of all controls created in runtime in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

// this function create mutiple htmlcontrol with id fileid1,fileid2, fileid3 etc "content_data" is a html div id.

protected void enter_rec_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    String control_data="";
    for (Int64 x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
    {
        control_data = control_data + "<input type='text' id='fileid" + x + "' runat='server' /> ";
    }

    content_data.InnerHtml = control_data;
}
```

//now in another btn click just access the controls

```
      for(Int64 i=1;i<=4;i++)
       {
        HtmlInputText text1,
        text1 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)Page.FindControl("fileid" + i);
        Response.write(text1.value); 
       }
```

but it can't find the control.i already include using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.
Help me..

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `Int64` for you loop variable that ha san upper limit of 4?

Comment: You are adding a String, not a control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering a string in the Div and not actually adding the control to the web-page so find control will not work you may have to read the html of the Div you are writing to to get the controls.

Alternatively add an actual control to the page to be able to use findcontrol.

i.e MyPannel.controls.add(new ctrl.....

Good Example found here :)
http://learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx